# How to resolve deserialization error in delayed job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job, deserialization

I am trying to use DelayedJob and the job is failing, giving the following error in the database:

```
{Delayed::DeserializationError
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb:7:in `yaml_new'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `transfer'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `node_import'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/yaml.rb:133:in `load'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:79:in `payload_object'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/backend/base.rb:87:in `invoke_job_without_newrelic_transaction_trace'
(eval):3:in `invoke_job'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/newrelic_rpm-2.13.4/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:252:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/newrelic_rpm-2.13.4/lib/new_relic/agent/method_tracer.rb:141:in `trace_execution_scoped'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/newrelic_rpm-2.13.4/lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/controller_instrumentation.rb:247:in `perform_action_with_newrelic_trace'
(eval):2:in `invoke_job'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:62:in `timeout'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:120:in `run'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:119:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:177:in `reserve_and_run_one_job'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:104:in `work_off'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `times'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:103:in `work_off'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:78:in `start'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/benchmark.rb:308:in `realtime'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:77:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `loop'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/worker.rb:74:in `start'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/tasks.rb:9
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:636:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:631:in `execute'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:597:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/monitor.rb:242:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:590:in `invoke_with_call_chain'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:583:in `invoke'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2051:in `invoke_task'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2029:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2023:in `top_level'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2001:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:2068:in `standard_exception_handling'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/lib/rake.rb:1998:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.8.7/bin/rake:31
/usr/bin/rake:19:in `load'
/usr/bin/rake:19
```

Not sure where to start in diagnosing this. This has never happened before and I have used delayed job before to serialize model objects without any issues. Why this time?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've been having this problem as well. It doesn't seem to happen every time, just sometimes.

Comment: Can you catch the error and print out the value it's trying to deserialize? It appears YAML is choking on your data somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure where to catch the error, as this seems to be occurring within DJ's code.

Comment: Maybe inspect your database and see what the stored value is on the failed job?

Comment: When the job fails, DJ deletes the record. Is there a way to shut that off?

Comment: To stop DJ from deleting the jobs, add 'Delayed::Worker.destroy_failed_jobs = false' to an initializer file.

Comment: Are you using MySQL as your database; and what version of Ruby are you using?

Comment: Do you have jobs which deterministically fail, or do they fail once or twice and eventually succeed? If the latter, could some of your workers be configured differently than the others (different version of ruby, etc)?

Answer (score 69, accepted):

It's not really a deserialization error, it's an ActiveRecord record-not-found error on a simple Model.find(id) query.

If you want to know the details, log them in the `delayed_job-2.1.3/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb` file, in the rescue statement, just before delayed-job stupidly raises the `DeserializationError` and throws the useful information away.

Comment: Wow, thank you for this. With that error, this is the last thing I'd suspect.

Answer (score 12):

Michiel is right.  Look at your handler field for objects like "!ruby/ActiveRecord:YourClassName"

Then check if objects can be retrieved via the primary key

From the console you can also test this out by doing something like:

```
# first job in your delayed queue
YAML.load(Delayed::Backend::ActiveRecord::Job.first.handler)
```

Answer (score 3):

I believe this occurs when you run a job against an unsaved or deleted AR object since the deserialization for AR loads the record by id. An exception should probably be thrown if you attempt to delay a method on an unsaved AR object.

Comment: yes I was stuck for hours and fixed it by making my before_save callback that called my DJ queue into an after_save callback

Answer (score 1):

There's also a documented bug with DJ when the params passed into the handler field in the DB are longer than a standard TEXT column:

https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/issues/491

If this happens to be your problem, changing the column to a MEDIUMINT should fix the issue.

I did this in a migration like so:

```
change_column :delayed_jobs, :handler, :text, :limit => 16777215
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("DELETE FROM delayed_jobs WHERE LENGTH(handler) >= 65535")
```

You can check to see if it's an issue with a simple DB query:

```
SELECT * FROM delayed_jobs WHERE LENGTH(handler) >= 65535
```

Answer (score 1):

If anyone wants to make delayed_job just finish the job as a no-op you can monkey patch with this code in the initializer:

https://gist.github.com/spilliton/8494752

Answer (score 0):

Today, I also suffered through this error and after doing hectic analysis found:

1. delayed_job converts methods & parameters to YAML format and stores it into database
2. It can be found using `select * from delayed_jobs`;
3. deserialization error occurs when delayed_job is not able to deserialize it.

Probable causes can be:

1. args["xyz"] used before calling delayed_job & inside worker using it as args[:xyz]
2. Sometimes extra arguments passed along with object to delayed_job that time delayed_job fails to build object as it is indifferent access.

I Hope this will help!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when we upgrade libs delayed jobs still keep old references.

Try to find the id of delayed_job in logs and play to parse its handler to ruby to find the wrong reference

```rb
j = DelayedJob.find(XXX)
data = YAML.load_dj(j.handler)
data.to_ruby
```

I made a [pull request](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/pull/1089) to help with this problem.

Meanwhile you can use this lines

```rb
# config/initializers/delayed_job.rb

# Monkey patch to use old class references
module Psych

  class << self; attr_accessor :old_class_references end
  @old_class_references = {}

  class ClassLoader
    private

    def find klassname
      klassname = ::Psych.old_class_references[klassname] || klassname
      @cache[klassname] ||= resolve(klassname)
    end
  end

  module Visitors
    class ToRuby < Psych::Visitors::Visitor
      def revive klass, node
        if klass.is_a? String
          klassname = ::Psych.old_class_references[klass] || klass
          klass = Kernel.const_get(klassname) rescue klassname
        end
        s = register(node, klass.allocate)
        init_with(s, revive_hash({}, node), node)
      end
    end
  end
end

# Add all old dependencies (hash keys) pointing to new references (hash values)
Psych.old_class_references = {
  'ActiveRecord::AttributeSet' => 'ActiveModel::AttributeSet'
  # ...
}
```