# Deserialization Error when loading ActiveRecord objects from YAML

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, yaml, delayed-job

Why do I get this error when I try to deserialize a new ActiveRecord object:

```
[Dev]> YAML.load(Identity.new.to_yaml)
Delayed::DeserializationError: Delayed::DeserializationError
```

while at the same time, this example with an existing AR object works as expected:

```
[Dev]> YAML.load(Identity.first.to_yaml)
=> #<Identity id: 1, ...
```

A few things that seem relevant, based on searching for answers:

I'm using `ruby 1.9.2p318`, `rails 3.1.3`, `delayed_job 2.1.4` and my `YAML::ENGINE.yamler` is `syck`.

What can I do so that I can serialize a new Identity record as YAML and then deserialize it later?

UPDATE: I also discovered that if I remove the `delayed_job` gem then this simple example does work, and my `YAML::ENGINE.yamler` is now `psych`. But I use `delayed_job` in my app, so it's still important to understand what's going on

Comment: [See if this helps](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023231/how-to-resolve-deserialization-error-in-delayed-job)

Answer (score 3):

Well the reason for that if you check the delayed_job structure there exist a file called [`serialization/active_record.rb`](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb)

Now for Ruby with `syck` (only of syck it happen) as the YAML engine the define `yaml_new` is invoke everytime `YAML.load` is called and if you examine the method technically it try to build the object from the database with the `id` extracted from the attributes of the object

so for this

`YAML.load(Identity.first.to_yaml)`

it internally does this

`Identity.find(1)`

but in your case `Identity.new` as no `id` associate with it so in this is throws you of  deserialization

I think the reason it took so long for people to respond to this question is that error listed by you

`Delayed::DeserializationError: Delayed::DeserializationError`

because it does state any information as to that there is `no primary` key present which it does [currently](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/blob/master/lib/delayed/serialization/active_record.rb#L8)

the reason I believe is [this](https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job/commit/8d3907764ecf557472cc680282710f4ccc459240) commit possible which is was pushed more or less  at the same time when the you posted the question but perhaps you where still using the old code in your machine did not reported it this

```
ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, class: #{klass} , primary key: #{val['attributes'][klass.primary_key]}
```

### NOTE :

It only happen for `syck` tested out `pysch` the method is not called at all perhaps it used for backward compatibility I guess